# Binding multiple variables in PL/SQL dynamic statement using 'USING'

Tags: plsql

There is a dynamic statement with multiple bind variables in which the same variable is used at multiple places. The dynamic statement will also vary depending on the conditions. So the order of bind variables will vary

How can i bind all the variables for specific names? E.g. all `:company_id` to reference to one value, all `:date_from` reference to one value and all `:date_to` to reference to one value.

```
SELECT emp_no
 FROM company_tab 
 WHERE company_id = :company_id 
 AND :template_id IS NOT NULL 
 AND :date_from IS NOT NULL 
 AND :date_to IS NOT NULL 
 AND emp_no in 
    (SELECT DISTINCT a.emp_no
      FROM tab1 t, tab2 a, tab3 w
     WHERE t.company_id = :company_id
       AND t.template_id = :template_id
       AND w.company_id = t.company_id
       AND w.param_id = t.param_id
       AND a.company_id = t.company_id
       AND a.param_id = t.param_id
       AND GREATEST(a.date_from, :date_from) >= :date_from
       AND a.date_from <= :date_to
       AND NVL(a.date_to, :date_to) >= :date_from
     UNION 
    SELECT distinct a.emp_no
      FROM tab1 t, tab4 a, tab5 d
     WHERE t.company_id = :company_id
       AND t.template_id = :template_id
       AND t.company_id = a.company_id
       AND t.param_id = a.param_id
       AND d.company_id = a.company_id
       AND a.data_deriv_day BETWEEN :date_from AND :date_to)
```

I want this to be done without using the REPLACE function and using USING statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `with` clause to bind the variables first...

```
with bind_val as (
    select 
        :company_id company_id,
        :template_id template_id,
        :date_from date_from,
        :date_to date_to
    from dual
)
SELECT 
    emp_no
FROM company_tab t 
join bind_val b 
on t.company_id = b.company_id 
where b.template_id IS NOT NULL 
AND b.date_from IS NOT NULL 
AND b.date_to IS NOT NULL 
AND t.emp_no in (
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT a.emp_no
    FROM tab1 t 
    join bind_val c 
    on t.company_id = c.company_id
    AND t.template_id = c.template_id
    join tab3 w
    on w.company_id = t.company_id
    AND w.param_id = t.param_id
    join tab2 a
    on a.company_id = t.company_id
    AND a.param_id = t.param_id

    where GREATEST(a.date_from, c.date_from) >= c.date_from
    AND a.date_from <= c.date_to
    AND NVL(a.date_to, c.date_to) >= c.date_from

    union all
    ......
)
```

Now you have only 4 bind variables, that can be used any number of times.

Note:-
Prefer using `join` instead of `,` to join the table.